# SwiftUI append data into structured array only if data didn't already inside

Tags: arrays, sorting, swiftui, append

I'm trying to add data into a structured array only if data didn't already exist in my array. I do that in a ForEach in my main view.

My code is :

```
ForEach(flightLibrary.testFlight.filter({Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date)})) { flight in
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
        NavigationLink(
            destination: {
                // .........
            }, label: {
                LogbookCellView2(flight: flight)
            }).accentColor(.black)
        
        let nameDepField = flight.depPlace
        let nameArrField = flight.arrPlace
        
        if !places.filter { $0.name.contains(nameDepField) }{
            let _ = places.append(PointOfInterest(name: nameDepField, latitude: getApLat(ApName: nameDepField) ?? 45, longitude: getApLong(ApName: nameDepField) ?? 15))
        }
        if !places.filter { $0.name.contains(nameArrField) }{
            let _ =  places.append(PointOfInterest(name: nameArrField, latitude: getApLat(ApName: nameArrField) ?? 45, longitude: getApLong(ApName: nameArrField) ?? 15))
        }  
    }
}
```

My array is defined as follow :

```
var places: [PointOfInterest] = []

struct PointOfInterest: Identifiable {

    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

And I would like to check if `places.name` match with `nameDepField` or `nameArrField` and if there is no match : add my new value.

But with my code where I used : `if !places.filter { $0.name.contains(nameDepField) }` xCode give me : `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions` in my `var body: some View` line.

I don't see how to manage this ...

Comment: That's the wrong place to do such operations. `ForEach` is not  the same as `forEach`.  Assuming `flightLibrary` is a view model run the code there (as well as the date filter). By the way filtering `places` twice in each iteration of `ForEach` is enormously expensive. And it doesn't  return a `Bool`, the exclamation mark makes no sense. And `filter` is the wrong API anyway to check if the item already exists because it evaluates **all** items. More efficient is `first` or `firstIndex` is not `nil`.

Comment: Oh ok, may I put a call for a function in a `ForEach` ?

Comment: No. This is not the way SwftUI works efficiently. Filter `testFlight` and update `places` somewhere else in a view model and `@Publish` the filtered data to the view.

Comment: This is a tricky one because they also depend on the current Calendar which should be `@Environment(\.calendar)` instead of `Calendar.current`. Perhaps a Places `DynamicProperty` struct with filter mutating funcs is the way to go.